# How to draw vis.js network in deterministic way?

Tags: javascript, vis.js

I have a JavaScript array where I store states of a network (for my application, each state is a different vis.js network). My problem is, when I draw each state, it is drawn randomly. So, I would like to know if it's possible stablish a seed or something that allows draw a network in deterministic way (I want always starts drawing the same thing with the same shape).

The goal is drawing each state seems a new node and some edges has been added, without it seems network has moved.

Is there any way to get it?

Thanks!

Answer (score 7):

Hey this might help but you do have the ability in the options to stipulate a randomSeed that does a deterministic drawing of your graph, other options also exist that allow a hierarchical layout and directions.

Please see the following list for all options and explanations: http://visjs.org/docs/network/layout.html.

```
var options = {
        layout: {
            randomSeed: 1,
            improvedLayout: true,
            hierarchical: {
                direction: 'LR',        // UD, DU, LR, RL
                sortMethod: 'directed'   // hubsize, directed
            }
        }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks for your response, Rohan. The problem persists and I can't find new clues for the solution.

Comment: Hey, could you create a simple plunker of what you are trying to achieve and I can see if I can help from there?